# network troubles on ASUS Maximus Hero VII

Tags: debian, networking, udev

I've installed my old desktop's motherboard and cpu in my server and I'm having some troubles with network interfaces.

The `eth0` interface fails to start and gets renamed to `eno1` and since my router has DHCP enabled and a fixed IP for the MAC-addr of the server the `eno1` interface gets a ip from the DHCP list.

```
holmen@filserver:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <mac addr> brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.139/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic eno1
       valid_lft 84195sec preferred_lft 84195sec
    inet6 fe80::7a24:afff:fe34:a01d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The static IP i want the router to give to the server is `192.168.1.2` and not `.139` that it gets.

I donwt have any rules in the udev rule catalogue and this is a fresh install

```
holmen@filserver:~$ ls -Al /etc/udev/rules.d/
total 0
```

I'm also missing the write_net_rules file that are supposed to be in this folder:

```
holmen@filserver:~$ ls -Al /lib/udev/
ata_id                  hwclock-set             iphone-set-info         mtd_probe               udev-add-printer
cdrom_id                hwdb.bin                ipod-set-info           mtp-probe               udev-configure-printer
collect                 hwdb.d/                 libinput-device-group   rules.d/                usb_modeswitch
hid2hci                 ifupdown-hotplug        libinput-model-quirks   scsi_id                 v4l_id
```

Can anyone  help me with my troubles?

EDIT:
I also get this error during boot, can it have something to do with it

```
holmen@filserver:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i 'lookup'
[    1.088164] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20160831/psargs-359)
[    1.090879] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20160831/psargs-359)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eno1` is the new `eth0`, introduced by the [Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) scheme. Your interface is up and running, it's just alled `eno1` instead of `eth0`. Your DHCP server is assigning an IP address to your server. You should investigate why the DHCP server is handing you a dynamic address and not the static address you want; this is not the client's fault. Re-check the DHCP server's configuration.

Comment: The router says: `filserver
192.168.1.139 Static
<mac addr>` and the DHCP page says: `<mac addr> 192.168.1.2` so its configured right, as far as i can see

Comment: i Found the culprit: `dnsmasq-dhcp[11011]: not using configured address 192.168.1.2 because it is leased to <old mac addr>` how can i flush this lease?

Comment: i am stupid, ignore me :D Hopefully this helps some other equally stupid person some time :)